# Print final value of variable on title-page

Tags: counters

TLDR; Is there a way I can use the final value of a variable at the beginning of a document?

I want to automatically generate a report by simply adding textblocks. Every textblock-occurence increases the according counter, which works pretty fine. For example, [cat, dog, bird] textblocks can be created. The variables `cnt_dog, cnt_cat, cnt_bird` are defined in advance and are increased by using `\newcommand{\catbox}{\addtocounter{cnt_cat}{1}}`.

Now the problem: When I access the variable (`\arabic{cnt_cat}`) at the end of the document (using TeX-Studio) everything works fine, but when I access the variable at the **beginning** of the document, the value is 0. Seems the parser does not update the previously used value in the end :/

Cheers, Andi

Answer (score 1):

you can use, at the end

```
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\setcounter{cnt_cat}{\arabic{cnt_cat}}}
```

(with `@` a letter)

then the `.aux` file will have something like

```
\setcounter{cnt_cat}{5}
```

so the counter will be set to 5 at `\begin{document}` on the next run.